# object has no attribute 'CreateImage'

Tags: python, opencv

```
import cv2 as cv
frame_copy = cv.CreateImage((frame.width, frame.height), cv.IPL_DEPTH_8U, frame.nChannels)
```

> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'CreateImage'

Функция изменилась с новой версии OpenCV?

Comment: Покажите импорты. И это, я бы добавил язык программирования в метки.

Comment: @post_zeew обновил.

Comment: А если попробовать [`cv.cv.CreateImage(...)`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23375958)?

Comment: Пробовал: 'module' object has no attribute 'cv'

Comment: Похоже, вы не первый, кто сталкивается с подобной проблемой: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23178007/error-creatimage-opencv